# Prime number finder runtime error

Tags: c++, primes

Using a variant of sieve of eratosthenes I wrote a piece of code in c++ which ought to calculate prime numbers and store them in a vector.
In the first part i took array ar of length 1000 using calloc() so that i get the values initialized as false of every array element and calculated and stored primes less than 1000 in the vector a.
In the second part I took values start and end , so that I'll find next prime numbers in range [start,end).
The code is working fine to calculate prime numbers (0,10000) but is giving runtime error if range to find prime numbers is greater than that.
Below is my code.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    bool *ar=(bool*)calloc(1000,sizeof(bool));
    vector<int> a;
    for(int i=2;i<1000;i++)
    {
        if(!ar[i])
        {
            a.push_back(i);
            for(int j=i*i;j<1000;j+=i)
                ar[j]=true;
        }
    }
    int start=1000,end=2000;
    while(start<10000)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
            ar[i]=false;
        for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
        {
            int m=start/a[i];
            if(start%a[i]>0)
                m++;
            for(int j=a[i]*m;j<end;j+=a[i])
                ar[j-start]=true;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
        {
            if(!ar[i])
            {
                a.push_back(i+start);
                for(int j=(i+start)*(i+start);j<end;j+=i+start)
                    ar[j-start]=true;
            }
        }
        start+=1000;
        end+=1000;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<' ';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: As for your problem, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: This code is full of terrible practices... Including [`#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/9254539), [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/9254539), and messing with dynamic memory allocation when you clearly know about the existence of `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend static declaration of array ar `bool ar[1000];` and then put assertion before accessing array `ar`, since there is some issue with your calculation. When you run your code, your IDE will stop before writing outside the array boundaries

```
a.push_back(i+start);
for(int j=(i+start)*(i+start);j<end;j+=i+start)
{
  assert(j-start >= 0 && j-start < 1000);
  ar[j-start]=true;
}
```